# Swagger API NodeJS module generation

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, swagger, mustache

New dev in Swagger and OpenAPI spec here.
By examining [swagger-js-codegen](https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen) I noticed that its developer uses a number of mustache tags in order to generate code for NodeJS.

I want to write my own template for NodeJS that takes into account the API call nesting, in respect to the following format:

```
/Module/Class/Method
```

For instance, my API should look like:

```
/Module1/MyClass1/InnerMethod
/Module1/MyClass2/InnerMethod
```

And in NodeJS usage:

```
var module1 = require("Module1");
var class1  = new module1.MyClass1();
class1.InnerMethod(); // Proxy call to the API.
```

There are 2 problems though:

1. In Swagger documentation, I am not sure how I could describe this
   in respect to the OpenAPI specification?
2. I haven't found any documentation on Swagger mustache tags, so that I could think on any workarounds I could do.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You may also want to try [Swagger  Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate API clients or server stubs in NodeJS.

Comment: Swagger codegen doesn't mention API Clients for NodeJs, it just generates JavaScript clients, May be we can modify it to make a client stub to be consumed by node.js